# Repeat or change cell value based on other cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a macro which fills values in Column G (starting at cell `G2`) based on user prompts for the start value, then repeats to the end of the column by adding 10 to the value each time.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim TagName As String
Dim TagNum As Long, k As Long

' Prompts user for tag names/numbers
TagName = InputBox("What is the product tag name? Ex. APPLE")
TagNum = InputBox("What is the starting tag #? Ex. 10")


' Set values in column G, up to last row in column J
k = 0
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With ActiveSheet.Range("G2")
    For i = 1 To LastRow Step 1
        .Item(i + 0) = TagName & "_" & TagNum2 + k
        k = k + 10
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

This works perfectly if Column C has unique values in each line, like so:
[image: Before]

But if the value in Column C repeats, I want the same in Column G, like this:
[image]

Comment: Will the repeating lines always be consecutive? If so, create branching logic. Say "If [Cell in C in current row] = [Cell in C in row above] , Then [Cell in G in current row] = [Cell in G in row above] Else [Cell in C in current row] = [Current formula] End If"

Comment: Yes the repeating lines in `Column C` will be consecutive, but not named so neatly with numbers at the end.  In other words, if `Parameter 5` repeats 4 times, you will never see `Parameter 1` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are couple of errors. Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim TagName As String, sTag As String
    Dim TagNum As Long, k As Long

    ' Prompts user for tag names/numbers
    TagName = InputBox("What is the product tag name? Ex. APPLE")
    TagNum = InputBox("What is the starting tag #? Ex. 10")

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        k = TagNum
        .Range("G2").Value = TagName & "_" & k
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            '~~> Increment k only if the values do not match
            If .Range("C" & i).Value <> .Range("C" & i - 1).Value _
            Then k = k + 10

            .Range("G" & i).Value = TagName & "_" & k
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I selected "Apple" and "10" in the Input Boxes

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this code will work as it does not have `k = k + 10` at the end of the `For` loop.  I need this so the values increment by 10.  For example, if the user enters `100` as the starting `TagNum`, then the values in your example above should be `Apple_100` `Apple_110` `Apple_110` etc

Comment: Do you always want to increment by 10?

Comment: Yes always by 10.  Also which line defines the first cell in `Column G` to populate?

Comment: Then see the updated code :) You may have to refresh the page. The first code was using `TagNum` to increment. In the second code the increment is happening at fixed interval of 10